# How to search text in PDF 1.7 files (from tools with gui or, better, from command line .bat or .sh files)?

Tags: pdf, adobe, livecycle, text-search

I need to search for text in a bulk of pdf files.

These files are "normal" PDF files and others are generated with Adobe Livecycle and are "PDF 1.7" files.

On the normal files I can search text using for example PDF-XChange Viewer (rif. http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) or Recoll (rif. http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) but they don't work on "PDF 1.7" files.

Are there some solutions that work on both types of PDF files?

Any suggestions? Thank you very much in advance

Cesare

Comment: Where are you seeing that they are "PDF 1.7" files? 1.7 is simply the latest version of the PDF standard, and shouldn't cause any unusual behavior.

Comment: Files created with Livecycle (Livecycle WHAT? Designer, Form Server, Document Server?) can be XFA files which have a PDF wrapper around them to make them suitable for displaying in Acrobat/Reader. PDF version 1.7 is the version allowing for that feature. However, it requires the XFA engine to properly display the file. As XFA is a variant of XML, you might be able to search the XML part.